# Unable to retrieve required object from parse.com User class using javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using the JavaScript SDK with I'm using parse.com.

The below code is meant to select the user thats currently logged in, then retrieve their "username" from the "User" class and show it in the console log.

> ```
> Parse.initialize("XXXX", "XXXX");
> var currentUser = Parse.User.current();    
> var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
> query.equalTo(currentUser);  
> query.find({
>   success: function(theuser) {
>     console.log(username);
>   }
> });
> ```

UPDATE, BASED ON THE ANSWER BELOW I TRIED

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var user = currentUser.get("username");
var user = currentUser.get("gender");
   console.log(user); 
   console.log(gender);
```

but now get Uncaught ReferenceError: gender is not defined ?

---

At the moment I'm getting the following error.

> POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User 400 (Bad Request)
>   parse-1.2.17.min.js:1 t._ajax parse-1.2.17.min.js:1 t._request
>   parse-1.2.17.min.js:1 t.Query.find parse-1.2.17.min.js:3 (anonymous
>   function)

This seems to say it cannot find the User class, but you can see from the screen shot this does exist. Can anyone help me with what the issue is here?

[image: parse backend]

[image: screen shots]

Answer (score 0):

With "var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); " you already have the current user object. Don't query for it. Just get the value from the object.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code your answer if you can just help answer the point I've raised I will accept your answer.

Comment: Besides the fact you're declaring var user twice, the screenshot does not show the user class having a gender field. Gender is not defined since you specified user instead of gender, I assume...

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
var user = currentUser.get("username");
var user = currentUser.get("gender"); //you also named this var 'user' instead of 'gender'
```

change this to:

```
var user = currentUser.get("username");
var gender = currentUser.get("gender");
```